# Java generics method overriding

Tags: java, generics

I have interface:

```
public interface CartService extends RemoteService{
    <T extends ActionResponse> T execute(Action<T> action);
}
```

I wish override 'execute' method in implementation:

```
public class XX implements CartService {

  @Override
  public <GetCartResponse> GetCartResponse execute(GetCart action) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
}
```

But receive compiler error:
The method execute(GetCart) of type XX must override or implement a supertype method

GetCart & GetCartResponse:

```
public class GetCart implements Action<GetCartResponse>{

}


public class GetCartResponse implements ActionResponse {
    private final ArrayList<CartItemRow> items;

    public GetCartResponse(ArrayList<CartItemRow> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<CartItemRow> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

How can I override this method ?

Comment: @blackliteon : Have you tried `public <GetCartResponse extends ActionResponse> GetCartResponse execute(GetCart action)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the definition of the interface vs what the erausre should look like for your impl. In your example you have:

```
<T extends ActionResponse> T execute(Action<T> action);
public <GetCartResponse> GetCartResponse execute(GetCart action);
```

but according to the interface definition the implementation method should read:

```
public GetCartResponse execute(Action<GetCartResponse> action);
```

So I think you either need to change the signature of your interface or add another type parameter such as:

```
public interface CartService extends RemoteService{
    <T extends ActionResponse, U extends Action> T execute(U action);
}
```

or possibly something along the lines of:

```
public interface CartService extends RemoteService{
    <T extends ActionItem> ActionResponse<T> execute(Action<T> action);
}
```

Comment: How did you coloured the text red in your first code snippet?

Comment: That's something the auto-syntax highlighter is doing automatically, not sure how or why.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface specifies that implementing classes must define that method for all `T extends ActionResponse`.  You want to define them for specific actions, and responses - I think your interface needs to be

```
    public interface CartService<T extends ActionResponse, A extends Action<T>>
     extends RemoteService {
      public T execute(A action)
    }
```

and then implementation would be

```
public class XX implements CartService<GetCartResponse,GetCart> {
 //...
}
```

As written, you may not need to explicitly parametrize with an extension of `Action` type - as long as you can deal with any kind of `Action` that is parametrized by `GetCartResponse` and don't rely on specifics of the `GetCart` action.  In which case, your interface should look something like:

```
public interface CartService<T extends ActionResponse> extends RemoteService {
 public T execute(Action<T> action);
}
```

and implementation

```
public class XX implements CartService<GetCartResponse> {
 public GetCartResponse execute(Action<GetCartResponse> action) {
  //...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public <GetCartResponse extends ActionResponse>
    GetCartResponse execute(GetCart action) {
    //do stuff
}
```

as the signature for the execute method in `CartService`, it should work.

I ahve tested that the follwing compiles; just substituted `ActionResponse` with `Integer`, and `Action` with `List`, for convenience.

CartService:

```
public interface CartService {
    <T extends Integer> T execute(List<T> action);
}
```

XX:

```
public class XX implements CartService {
    public <T extends Integer> T execute(List<T> action) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```